# Get value for Textbox with separator 

Tags: jquery

I'd like get a string with the value from some Textbox (with a specific class) and the values should be separate by a comma.

Any idea ?

Thanks,

Update1 :

I have this

```
   <input type="text" id="A" class="test" value="aa">
   <input type="text" id="B" class="test" value="bb">
```

I'd like this : aa,bb

Comment: What do you mean by *"and the values should be separate by a comma"* , do you want to validate the input, or do you want to add the commas with javascript?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

get the value then use [split](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_split.asp).

```
var str = 's,s,e,a,t,f';
var str2 = str.split(",");
alert(str2[2])​;​ // alerts e
```

you can do `var str = $('#someTextbox').val()` then proceed as above.

that is if I understood you clearly.

---

In your update, you can do it this way,

```
var str = $('.test').map(function(){
    return this.value;
}).get().join(',');
```

`str` now holds all the values found separated by comma, [here's a demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rgdsa/) cause I'm not good at explaining... :)